# Monotouch stringWithFormat using a URL

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, stringwithformat

I'm trying to learn the MapKit with Monotouch and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to search for an address.  I finally found this snippet of Objective-C code that might help but it has a line where they use a URL to get a return value and I have no idea how to use this code in C#:

`NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                    [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

If anyone could give me some advice that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
string urlString = String.Format(@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q={0}&output=csv", System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(addressField.text))
```

Comment: Oops, I posted the wrong snippet of code but thanks for your correct answer!
:)

Answer (score 0):

For urls try this

```
var uri = new Uri (url);
var nsurl = new NSUrl (uri.GetComponents (UriComponents.HttpRequestUrl, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (nsurl);
```